# Java FX control for enter date in timestamp format

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Tell me please, is there any visual component for enter date in timestamp format, DatePicker supports date only, as I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX 8 does not have a time chooser.

But the [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) project has few useable components called as [`LocalDateTimePicker`](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/blob/2.2/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/scene/control/LocalDateTimePicker.java) and `LocalTimePicker`

The [Source Code](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs) for the project. Though I am not sure why it was discontinued on the 8.0 branch.

Answer (score 0):

jdk1.8.0_40 has a DatePicker and a Spinner control.